# tikzpicture as \newcommand with argument(s)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have a tikz barplot which I want as a `\newcommand` with a variable. Depending on the variable, labels should be added or not. In the document I will use the plot several times, sometimes with, sometimes without labels. Thats why I want it as a command.

here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myplotWithoutLabels}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar, bar shift=0pt, bar width=20pt, xmin=0,
axis x line = none, axis y line* = middle, 
ytick={1,2,3}, tickwidth=0, every tick/.style={draw=none},% label pos, no   tick marks
yticklabels={}
]
\addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\myplotWithoutLabels

\newcommand{\myplotWithLabels}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar, bar shift=0pt, bar width=20pt, xmin=0,
axis x line = none, axis y line* = middle, 
ytick={1,2,3}, tickwidth=0, every tick/.style={draw=none},
yticklabels={L1, L2, L3}
]
\addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\myplotWithLabels
\end{document}
```

I've tried several things, i.e.:

```
\newcommand{\myplot}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=my Title,
xbar, bar shift=0pt, bar width=20pt, xmin=0,
axis x line = none, axis y line* = middle,
ytick={1,2,3}, tickwidth=0, every tick/.style={draw=none},
yticklabels={#1, #3, #3}
]
\addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\myplot[L1,L2,L3]
```

or with only one (#1) argument. Neither did work.

The solution to this question [Problem declaring newcommand with tikzpicture inside](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/problem-declaring-newcommand-with-tikzpicture-inside) didn't help me either.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the comments and answers. Now the `\newcommand` works. However, there is one problem left. The plot generated with the `\newcommand` with argument is slightly shifted up on the y axis.

Here the code, I've put the two plots next to each other using subcaption package (`\usepackage{subcaption}`)  to see the difference. The plots are both as \newcommand, one without argument, one with argument.

```
\newcommand{\myplot}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar, bar shift=0pt, bar width=20pt, xmin=0,
axis x line = none, axis y line* = middle,
ytick={1,2,3}, tickwidth=0, every tick/.style={draw=none},
yticklabels={#1}
]
\addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.45\textwidth}
\myplotWithoutLabels
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h!]{0.45\textwidth}
\myplot{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image: plots next to each other]

I can't find the reason for the shift.

Comment: It should be `yticklabels={#1,#2,#3}` and `\myplot{L1}{L2}{L3}`. Or declare `\myplot` to have a single argument, coding `yticklabels{#1}`; then the call `\myplot{L1,L2,L3}` would be good.

Comment: To see how `\newcommand` works, consider reading [How to create new commands with multiple arguments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147642/5764)

Comment: What egreg said works, for the version without label just write `\myplot{}{}{}`.

Comment: How is `\myplotWithoutLabels` defined? You don't want `h!` as the placement option for `figure`, but you really, really, really don't want it for `subfigure` where it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two choices; which one depends very much on the application.

Remember that if you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{...}
```

then a call to `\foo` should be of the form

```
\foo{first}{second}{third}
```

where each argument is braced. It's not the same as in other programming language: the syntax `\foo{first,second,third}` would take `first,second,third` as `#1` and TeX would look further for `#2` and `#3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myplotA}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=20pt,
    xmin=0,
    axis x line = none,
    axis y line* = middle, 
    ytick={1,2,3},
    tickwidth=0,
    every tick/.style={draw=none},% label pos, no   tick marks
    yticklabels={#1,#2,#3},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
  \addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
  \addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\myplotB}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=20pt,
    xmin=0,
    axis x line = none,
    axis y line* = middle, 
    ytick={1,2,3},
    tickwidth=0,
    every tick/.style={draw=none},% label pos, no   tick marks
    yticklabels={#1},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
  \addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
  \addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\myplotA{L1}{L2}{L3}

\bigskip

\myplotB{L1,L2,L3}

\end{document}
```

As you see in the picture, the output is the same.

[image]

Comment: I now realise that my code is identical to yours and that the only difference between yours and that in the OP's edit is that the OP removed your comment signs which I then put back. Not only is it an egreg answer, it is egreg's answer. Do you want to add some explanation and I delete mine?

Answer (score 2):

This is really an egreg answer, because egreg specialises in this ;).

Your definition introduces spurious spaces because you have not commented line endings which TeX interprets as spaces.

I don't know how your second definition is done, so I adapted your first to take an optional, rather than mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,pgfplots}
\newcommand*{\myplot}[1][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar,
      bar shift=0pt,
      bar width=20pt,
      xmin=0,
      axis x line = none,
      axis y line* = middle,
      ytick={1,2,3},
      tickwidth=0,
      every tick/.style={draw=none},
      yticklabels={#1}
      ]
      \addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
      \addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
      \addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \myplot
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \myplot[L1,L2,L3]
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This reproduces the issue:

[image: misaligned plots]

Removing the spurious spaces fixes the issue.

[image: aligned plots]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,pgfplots}
\newcommand*{\myplot}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xbar,
      bar shift=0pt,
      bar width=20pt,
      xmin=0,
      axis x line = none,
      axis y line* = middle,
      ytick={1,2,3},
      tickwidth=0,
      every tick/.style={draw=none},
      yticklabels={#1}
      ]
      \addplot coordinates {(2,1)};
      \addplot coordinates {(5,2)};
      \addplot coordinates {(4,3)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \myplot
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \myplot[L1,L2,L3]
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have removed the `h!` specifier from the `subfigure`s because it makes no sense there and is not even defined, as far as I know. `subfigure` takes the same placement specifiers as `minipage` according to the manual.

I have not removed it from `figure` because it is defined there. However, you certainly should not use it. It never makes sense to give only `h` as the location specifier. If you really don't want the figure to more, don't use a float.