# Newcommand for TikZ Diagram with Arguments as Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm trying to make a macro to print a TikZ diagram with "variable" labels.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand[3]{\myDiagram}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[label={270:$1$}] (1) at (270:1) {};
    \node[label={30:$2$}] (2) at (30:1) {};
    \node[label={150:$3$}] (3) at (150:1) {};
    \draw
    (1) edge node[label={#1}] {} (2)
    (1) edge node[label={#2}] {} (3)
    (2) edge node[label={#3}] {} (3)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\myDiagram{$1$}{$2$}{$3$}
\end{document}
```

**Expected Behaviour**: A diagram which substitutes labels from argument.  I.e. My MWE's Output should be the same as this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[label={270:$1$}] (1) at (270:1) {};
  \node[label={30:$2$}] (2) at (30:1) {};
  \node[label={150:$3$}] (3) at (150:1) {};
  \draw
  (1) edge node[label={$1$}] {} (2)
  (1) edge node[label={$2$}] {} (3)
  (2) edge node[label={$3$}] {} (3)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Actual Behaviour**: I keep getting a `Missing \endcsname inserted.`

**What I've Tried**: Variations on [this question's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/problem-declaring-newcommand-with-tikzpicture-inside?noredirect=1&lq=1) (I couldn't find much else in the way of similar questions).

Please explain what I'm doing wrong here and how I can fix it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\myDiagram}[3]{%
\path
(-90:1) node (1) {$1$}
(30:1)  node (2) {$2$} 
(150:1) node (3) {$3$}
;
\draw[nodes={red,midway,scale=.6}] (1)
--(2) node[below right] {#1}
--(3) node[above] {#2}
--(1) node[below left] {#3}
;
}%  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\myDiagram{$1$}{$3$}{$2$} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also you can define a `pic` for this task.

**About the error in OP's code** OP made a wrong order: `\newcommand{\myDiagram}[3]` instead of `\newcommand[3]{\myDiagram}`.

Comment: This is a decent workaround, but doesn't address the "why is this not working" part of my question...  Also, why `\newcommand*` here (it doesn't affect the output on my machine)?

Comment: @User12345 I see the picture, then caring how to code with simplicity. I don't care much about the error in your code. although I think that is easy to explain. Maybe someone can help you, or you can explain yourself later

Comment: @User12345 aha, you made a wrong order: `\newcommand{\myDiagram}[3]` instead of `\newcommand[3]{\myDiagram}`

Comment: yup, silly me.  Thanks.

Comment: It happens sometimes ^^ Cheer up! I suppose that you can upvote and accept my updated answer now

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is the result of a `ID-10t error`.  As @Black Mild pointed out in a comment on their answer, I passed `\newcommand[3]{\myDiagram}` instead of  `\newcommand{\myDiagram}[3]`.